# Can Nutella be substituted for Peanut Butter in Peanut Butter Fudge?

Tags: substitutions, fudge

Want to substitute Nutella for peanut butter in M&M Peanut Butter Fudge.

Comment: you mean you want to replace peanut butter with Nutella? Might want to make that more clear, and [edit] your question to add the recipe.

Comment: How much difference are you prepared to accept?  A lot I hope.  There's a chance it won't set, but that depends on the quantities, so it would be helpful if you post the recipe.

Comment: Without the recipe, the best answer could only be "maybe" -- please do include it!

Answer (score 2):

The critical differences in a fudge recipe will be the amount of fat, nut solids, and other ingredients that might interfere with texture and setting. Since fudge gets its texture from a cooled suspension of solids in fat, and having the right concentration of sugar cooked enough to get to the correct temperature, these are the critical ingredients to consider for this type of substitution. From the nutition information:

> Nutrition Facts
>
> Peanut butter, smooth style
>
> Amount Per 2 tbsp (32 g)
>
> Calories 188
>
> Total Fat 16 g

---

> Nutrition Facts
>
> Nutella, original
>
> Amount Per 2 tbsp (37 g)
>
> Calories 200
>
> Total Fat 11 g

So, Nutella has soy lecithin as well, which can affect texture. You will notice that the fat percentage, as grams per gram of substance is considerably lower for nutella, but it has sugar, cocoa powder etc. This means that less fat = more binding, but other ingredients = less binding.

The long and short is you have to experiment. Nutella has other ingredients, too, like milk or milk solids and generally has a lighter texture than peanut butter. Experiment and you will then have to adjust other ingredients, like chocolate type or powder, butter, cream, etc... The greater sugar content is also important.